# Irregular behaviour of vectors in OpenCL(1.2) kernels

Tags: opencl, vectorization, gpgpu, opencl-c

So, I am trying to perform some operation inside an OpenCL kernel. I have this buffer named filter which is a 3x3 matrix initialized with value 1.

I pass this as an argument to the OpenCL kernel from the host side. The issue is when I try to fetch this buffer on the device side as a float3 vector.  For ex -

```
__kernel void(constant float3* restrict filter)
{
        float3 temp1 = filter[0];
        float3 temp2 = filter[1];
        float3 temp3 = filter[2];
}
```

The first two temp variables behave as expected and have all their value as 1. But, the third temp variable (temp3) has only the x component as 1 and rest of the y and z components are 0. When I fetch the buffer as only a float vector, everything behaves as expected. Am I doing something wrong? I don't want to use vload instructions as they give an overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OpenCL, `float3` is just an alias for `float4`, so your 9 values will fill the `x`, `y`, `z`, and `w` component of `temp1` and `temp2`, which leaves just one value for `temp3.x`. You will probably need to use the [vload3](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.1/docs/man/xhtml/vloadn.html) instruction.

See section [6.1.5. Alignment of Types](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/2.2/html/OpenCL_C.html#alignment-of-types) of the OpenCL specification for more information:

> For 3-component vector data types, the size of the data type is `4 * sizeof(component)`. This means that a 3-component vector data type will be aligned to a `4 * sizeof(component)` boundary. The **vload3** and **vstore3** built-in functions can be used to read and write, respectively, 3-component vector data types from an array of packed scalar data type.